# Why is the Legendre transformation an application of the duality relationship between points and lines?

Tags: mathematical-physics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

When I read the Wiki about [Legendre transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation), there is a statement

> The Legendre transformation is an application of the duality relationship between points and lines.

What's the meaning of this statement?

Comment: Legendre transformations connect point geometry and [Pluecker geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates). Check this [link](http://robotics.technion.ac.il/people/alon/appendix%20a.htm) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a convex function you can do the following:

For each point on the graph of the function, draw the line tangent to the function at that point.  That point can now be identified by its original $x$ and $y=f(x)$ coordinates, or by specifying the slope of that tangent line and its corresponding y-intercept.  Each point maps to one and only one line, and *vice versa*.  For convex functions, the mapping is one-to-one.  There is no ambiguity.  Draw a sketch and you will soon be convinced.

The Legendre transformation gives you the value of the y-intercept if you give it the slope. So the Legendre transform is a plot of  $b(m)$ *vs* $m$  (y-intercept as a function of slope) rather than $f(x)$ *vs* $x$.  Either function represents the same data or concept.  In a sense they contain the same information.

**update** Thanks to @EmilioPisanty for improved wording.  See comments.

Comment: This is not quite correct (in language; the content is OK). You can't specify both the slope and the y-intercept of a line, in the same way that you don't have freedom over $x$ and $y$ independently.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I agree completely.  Is this it? --- given $x$, then $y=f(x)$ is specified and "fixed".  Similarly, given $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x$, the L.T. specifies (and "fixes") the y-intercept (of the line having that slope that is also tangent to $f(x)$ somewhere).

Comment: I would phrase your third sentence as something like "That point can now be identified by its original $x$ adn $y=f(x)$ coordinates, or by specifying the slope of that tangent line and its corresponding $y$-intercept." (But of course that's my phrasing.)

Comment: Yes, it's your phrasing, but I still like it better than mine.  Thanks.  Editing answer.